# JQuery radio buttonset active and non active

Tags: jquery, user-interface, button

All right so I tried using the button set.

So fair, I have been able to transform them into links.
But, the thing is the radio buttons don't keep their active state.

Here is the code of jquery:

```
$( "#radio" ).buttonset();

$("input:radio[name=radio]").click(function() {
var id = $("input[@name=radio]:checked").attr('id');
window.location.replace("player.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&action="+id);
}
```

Here is the code of the butonset + the PHP code behind my web page:

```
<form>
 <div id="radio" class="ui-buttonset">
 <input type="radio" id="season" name="radio" value="season" /><label                  for="season">Season</label>
 <input type="radio" id="playoff" name="radio" value="playoff" /><label for="playoff">Playoffs</label>
 <input type="radio" id="carrer" name="radio" value="carrer" /><label for="carrer">Carrer</label>
 <input type="radio" id="carrer_playoff" name="radio" id="carrer_playoff"/><label for="carrer_playoff">Carrer playoffs</label>
 </div>
</form>
</center>

<br/><br/>

<?php
 if($action == "playoff"){
 include("player_playoff.php");
 }
 else if($action == "carrer"){
 include("player_carrer.php");
 }
 else if($action == "carrer_playoff"){
 include("player_carrer_playoff.php");
 }
 else{
 include("player_season.php");
 }

?>
```

This is the web page:
http://uweave.ca/uw-perso/Aravinthan_Sivaneswaran/COD_Circuit-TW/public%20v2.0/player.php?id=1&action=season

Thank you for your help,
Ara

EDIT:
        if($radio.is(':checked') === false) {
            $radio.filter('[value=]').attr('checked', true);
        }
        if($radio.filter('[value=]').attr('checked', true)){
            alert("IN");
        }

I did this to check, but it always alerts me with IN but it doesnt put it in checked ( active ) state...

Comment: You're reloading the page when the button is clicked. Why would the button keep its state?

Comment: Ahhhhh...Of course!!!!! I feel so stupid now!!!

Comment: strange UI ...Why would you use radios for page navigation?

Comment: I tought it would be easier for me to keep the active state with Radio buttons instead of normal buttons. But yeah, I forgot about reloading part...

Comment: How can I keep the state then? Is there a way to force a Radio button to be active?

Comment: Alright, so this is what I did

      if($radio.is(':checked') === false) {
   $radio.filter('[value=<?php echo $action; ?>]').attr('checked', true);
  }

But it still doesnt put it as checked...
To check it, I made this:
      if($radio.filter('[value=<?php echo $action; ?>]').attr('checked', true)){
   alert("IN");
  }
And it sends me an alert of IN

Comment: make sure you it is checked before invoking buttonset()

Comment: Ok so I put the code that checks and puts it as checked and then I put the buttonset(). But it still doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading comments to your question, here is what you are looking for

```
$(function(){
    $('input:radio[id="<?php echo $action; ?>"]').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seLTY/